# Is there an OpenVMS EDT keypad plugin for gedit?

Tags: plugins, keyboard-layout, gedit, edt, openvms

Is there [a](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=openvms+%22the+open+is+silent%22) [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [EDT](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6489/6489pro_contents_003.html#toc_chapter_9) [keypad](http://www.openvms.compaq.com/doc/73final/6021/6021pro_019.html#eve_edtequivs_ax) ([layout](http://openbookproject.net/tutorials/kjcole/kbd-edt.html)) plugin for [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/)?

Comment: also, URLs in markdown need double-quotes to be URL encoded (`%22`).

Comment: Should we consider moving this to SF?  OpenVMS is more their bag...

Comment: There's none as of now.

Comment: No, but emacs has EDT emulation so it may be possible to port that.

Answer (score 2):

There are none listed at the [Gnome Gedit plugin page](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins) but that page does have a list of "Requested plugins" - maybe you can get your idea listed there?

I know very little about Gedit and GTK but it [appears](http://codewordz.com/linux/use-emacs-keyboard-shortcuts-on-gedit-or-globally/) Gedit should recognise the GTK-key-theme settings. If so, you might be able to develop one that provides the VMS EDT layout by adapting an example such as [vim GTK key bindings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vi_key_bindings_in_gtk)